# How the point manipulator function is working?

Tags: c++, iostream, ostream

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ostream& point(ostream& s)  //Point a manipulator func
{       
    s << "-->";
    return s;

}

int main()    
{    
    cout << point << 10;
    return 0;
}
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------//

Comment: Replace its body with `s << "-->"; return s;`

Comment: Use full, explanatory sentences. What is it that you don't understand? And turn on your compiler warnings while you're at it.

Comment: Now the code is different. What code are we supposed to be looking at? Talk to us. Use your words.

Answer (score 1):

Badly.

That function has several bugs.

1. It streams directly to `cout`, regardless of what `s` is. So if you streamed `point` to another stream, not `cout`, the result would go to the wrong place.
2. It is missing a `return` statement, so your program has undefined behaviour. Your compiler should have warned you about that. You're supposed to return the stream again to permit chaining. This is a convention expected by the IOStream.

It could be correctly written like this:

```
ostream& point(ostream& s)
{
   s << "-->";
   return s;
}
```

This version "works" because IOStreams are specifically designed to accept a "pointer-to-function" of this form and to execute it with a reference to the stream as its first argument. It's a feature. It's how the IO manipulators (including `endl`!) do their job.

Answer (score 0):

The output stream class has some overloads taking certain function pointers as parameters. In particular there is an output operator declared as (ignorung that there are actually templates involved):

```
std::ostream& std::ostream::operator<< (
     std::ostream& (*manip)(std::ostream&));
```

When this operator is called it calls the passed function with itself, i.e., something like this:

```
manip(*this);
```

That is, “inserting” such a *manipulator* function causes the function to be called with the stream as argument..

Comment: I dont understand what does this means "(*manip)(std::ostream&)" ?

Comment: @Udesh: this is part if the type of a pointer to a function (it is missing the return type): in general it looks like `R(*name)(A...)`. `R` is the return type (in this case `std::ostream&`), `name` is simply the name and the `*` in front of it is indicating that it is a pointer. `A...` is the list of parameter types, in this case just `std::ostream&`. You get a function pointer by taking a functions address using `&f` or by decay to a pointer when a function is named in a context where a function pointer is expected (this is what is normally used for manipulators).